# Federated Apollo Graph - Join Entities Across Subgraphs (Elixir/Absinthe)

Tags: reactjs, graphql, elixir, apollo, absinthe

I am using Elixir/Phoenix with Absinthe to define a federated graph in Apollo. I have looked through the [Odyssey Voyage I](https://github.com/apollographql/odyssey-voyage-I) course but cant seem to piece together what I need. Here is my scenario:

I have two services (or subgraphs). One is the ProjectLocation subgraph and the other is the Inspection subgraph. A ProjectLocation can have 1 to many Inspections. What I need is to query a ProjectLocation and get it back with all of it's Inspections based on inspection parameters. I have my modules separated out into types, mutations, queries, resolvers, and then import them all into one schema file.

**ProjectLocation Subgraph Type**

```
defmodule MyProject.Schema.Types.ProjectLocation do


use Absinthe.Schema.Notation

  object :project_location do
    field :id, :id
    field :project_id, :id
    field :address, :string
  end

  input_object :input_project_location_params do
    field :id, :id
    field :project_id, :id
    field :address, :string
  end
end
```

**ProjectLocation Subgraph Query**

```
defmodule MyProject.Schema.Queries.ProjectLocation do
  use Absinthe.Schema.Notation

  alias MyProject.Schema.Resolvers

  object :project_location_queries do

    @desc "Find ProjectLocation"
    field :project_location, type: :project_location do
      arg(:project_location_id, non_null(:id))
      resolve(&Resolvers.ProjectLocation.get_project_location/3)
    end
    
  end
end
```

**Inspection Subgraph Type**

```
defmodule MyInspectionProject.Schema.Types.Inspection do
    use Absinthe.Schema.Notation

    object :inspection do
      field :id, :id
      field :project_id, :id
      field :inspection_location, :id //This is the project location id (bad naming on my part)
      field :status, :string
    end

    @desc "Inspection"
    input_object :input_inspection_params do
      field :id, :id
      field :project_id, :id
      field :inspection_location, :id
      field :status, :string
    end
  end
```

**Inspection Subgraph Query**

```
defmodule MyInspectionProject.Schema.Queries.Inspection do
    use Absinthe.Schema.Notation

    alias MyInspectionProject.Schema.Resolvers

    object :inspection_queries do
      @desc "Find Inspection"
      field :inspection, type: :inspection do
        arg(:inspection, non_null(:input_inspection_params))
        resolve(&Resolvers.Inspection.get_inspection/3)
      end
    end
  end
```

Using a React front end we would write the query for a project location like this:

```
const GET_PROJECT_LOCATIONS = gql`
  query ProjectLocations($projectId: ID!) {
    projectLocations(projectId: $projectId) {
      id
      projectId
      address
    }
  }
`;
```

My question I guess is how do I set up the types and write the query to preload and query the inspections as a "subquery?" Is it as simple as setting up an Inspection type in the ProjectLocation subgraph and writing the query somewhere along the lines of this?

```
const GET_PROJECT_LOCATIONS = gql`
  query ProjectLocations($projectId: ID!) {
    projectLocations(projectId: $projectId) {
      id
      projectId
      address
      inspection($status: STRING){
         id
         project_id
         inspection_location
         status
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

If so what would the variables object look like to pass into this GraphQL call. Also forgot to mention I'm using the useLazyQuery hook from the Apollo Client library in React.

Answer (score 2):

That graphql would be valid if the inspection `status` was also an arg to the root query (2nd arg, after projectID). See here for an example: https://elixirforum.com/t/why-do-you-have-to-re-declare-types-in-graphql-queries-when-you-use-variables/52723/10

It would look like this for you:

```
  query ProjectLocations($projectId: ID!, $status: STRING) {
    projectLocations(projectId: $projectId) {
```

Also add an `:inspection` field in your `project_location` object definition. There you can handle the `status` arg by writing the field with a resolve function. It will look like this:

```
field :inspection, :inspection do
  resolve(fn project_location, args, resolution ->
    inspection = get_inspection(project_location, args)
    {:ok, inspection}
  end)
end
```

Comment: In my resolver module in the Inspection subgraph, there is a function get_inspection (forgot to mention that). Would the get_inspection you've indicated here resolve to that? Or is this a separate function defined in the ProjectLocation subgraph?

Comment: Your query is to get the `inspection` as a property on the `project_location` object. Therefore you need the args to work on the resolve function as defined on the `field :inspection` in the `:project_location` object. The `get_inspection` function I wrote can be anything. It is up to you. For now, I would make a new function and work with that to make it do what you need it to do. Then, when it is working, consider if it could be consolidated with the resolver you use for the other `getInspection` query.